# The onPause() method gets called between activities

Tags: kotlin, onpause

I’m using the onPause() method in my app so that users become ‘offline’ in my chat when the app is on pause. I found it very useful.

But the thing is that each time a user navigates between activities, the method is called for like a millisecond. This way, users are ‘online’ in activity A, ‘online’ in B, but ‘offline’ in between.

Because I use a green dot to described online users, it is very annoying since it changes to grey and then green again each time.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: I would use a single activity, and use Fragments within that activity for the different screens.

Answer (score 1):

`onPause` is part of the *Activity lifecycle*, which relates to the different states an `Activity` goes through - it's not about whether your app as a whole is in the background. [Here's what the docs say about it](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#onpause)

> The system calls this method as the first indication that the user
> is leaving your activity (though it does not always mean the activity is being destroyed); it indicates that the activity is no longer in the foreground (though it may still be visible if the user is in multi-window mode).

There are a few ways you could handle it - the simplest would be to have a `navigating` flag you set when you're switching to activity B. Then the `onPause` can check that flag, and skip setting you to offline if there's a navigation even going on.

---

I'm assuming you mean the dot is flashing for *other* users (since you wouldn't be looking at the same `View` if you're the one switching between activities) - it might actually be a good idea to have the app send out an "I'm online" ping every so often anyway.

That way they can set a user to offline if they don't get a message after a certain amount of time - it just means that if a user gets a crash, their network drops or whatever, they don't look online the whole time just because they didn't send an "I'm offline now" message through `onPause`

Comment: Actually flagging sounds the best solution since the data change (to offline) also triggers the onDatchange() method. Could you please tell me what’s the best practice to flag the movements between activity A to B?

Comment: I just meant having a ``var navigating = false`` that you set to ``true`` just before you call ``startActivity`` (or whatever you're doing) to navigate to ``ActivityB``. If ``onPause`` checks that before it sets the online state, it knows whether to skip doing that